# How to implement MongoDB query in Laravel 5?

Tags: mongodb, laravel, laravel-5

I created mongodb query which I have to use in laravel controller.

My query is

```
db.PMS.aggregate([
    { $match: { "PanelID": "A00898" } },
    { 
        $project: { EventTS: 1, MainsPower: 1, } 
    },
    {
        $unwind: {
            path: "$MainsPower",
            includeArrayIndex: "arrayIndex",
            preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true
        }
    },
    {
        $project: {
            MainsPower: 1,
            timestamp: {
                "$add": [
                    "$EventTS",
                    { "$multiply": [ 60000, "$arrayIndex" ] }
                ]
            }
        }
    }
]);
```

I tried to use this query in a laravel function but I am little confused. Please help me how to implement this query in laravel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perform raw expressions on the internal MongoCollection object to run the aggregation:

```
$result = DB => collection('PMS')->raw(function ($collection){
    return $collection->aggregate(array(
        array( '$match' => array( "PanelID" => "A00898" ) ),
        array( '$project' => array( 'EventTS' => 1, 'MainsPower' => 1 ) ),
        array(
            '$unwind' => array(
                'path' => "$MainsPower",
                'includeArrayIndex' => "arrayIndex",
                'preserveNullAndEmptyArrays' => true
            )
        ),
        array(
            '$project' => array(
                '_id' => 0,
                'MainsPower' => 1,
                'timestamp' => array(
                    "$add" => array(
                        "$EventTS",
                        array( "$multiply" => array( 60000, "$arrayIndex" ) )
                    )
                )
            )
        )
    ));
});
```

Comment: query output in object format how to convert in to array

Comment: @dhanashri Since the original problem is solved, can you create a new question for this issue please?

Comment: ok but last question related to this question i want remove _id, So where i put  _id:0 please suggest me... @chridam

Comment: @dhanashri Again, this is considered bad practice as [**chameleon questions**](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43478/exit-strategies-for-chameleon-questions) are not encouraged here on SO. Notwithstanding this, I have updated the answer to include how you can remove the `_id` field.